# Fetch XMPP Open Fire Private Chat History and Message Archiving in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am working on XMPP Open fire i was able to send and receive the Message in Private Chat and also in Room and also able to get Chat History Of Room Chat but not able to get Message History Of Private Chat and i also wants to achieve the Message Archiving in Private Chat and Room Chat For Android.

Answer (score 4):

## Private Messaging Archives in XMPP

Private chat history is not stored by default on XMPP servers. Private messages that not yet were delivered to a client are stored as **"offline messages"**, if enabled on the server. As soon as a client reconnects, these are automatically delivered and purged. Your client will receive them like normal messages, except that they will contain a [timestamp of their initial transmission](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0203.html).

For a more persistent approach, there is [XEP-0136: Message Archiving](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) that never was widely used, or the better (and easier to implement) **[XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html)**.

## Server Support for XEP-0313

For **Openfire**, there was [a patch attached to OF-862](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-862) that has been merged in September 2015 and is part of the **4.0** release.

There is also support in ejabberd and prosody, if you take a recent enough version.

In either case you will need to [enable archiving for your account on the server](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#prefs).

## Client Support for XEP-0313

Depending on the client library you use, it might have support already, or you need to extend it with the appropriate XML extension code.

If you are using **[Smack](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)** (the most widely used Android XMPP library), it is not yet supported out-of-the-box, but the Smack maintainer has a [local branch with MAM support](https://github.com/Flowdalic/Smack/tree/mam), and [MAM will be incorporated into the next release](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-625).

You will need to instanciate a [`MamManager`](https://github.com/Flowdalic/Smack/blob/mam/smack-experimental/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/mam/MamManager.java) for your connection, and can obtain the archive content by using the [`queryArchive()`](https://github.com/Flowdalic/Smack/blob/mam/smack-experimental/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/mam/MamManager.java#L83) method. In the MAM branch, there is no built-in mechanism to configure the account archiving preferences, but I suppose that will also be fixed in the next release.